# curl --noproxy "*" equivalent in Python's request module

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to access an API on a server within my network using Python's `request` module, but am getting a 502 Bad Gateway error. When I try to do something equivalent using `curl`, I get the same error and it's because the request is trying to run through the proxy server. Here is the output from `curl`:

```
$ curl -v -k -u username:password https://hostname:port/some/api/endpoint              * Uses proxy env variable no_proxy == 'hostname'
* Uses proxy env variable https_proxy == 'http://10.3.0.40:10256'
*   Trying 10.3.0.40...
* TCP_NODELAY set
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 10.3.0.40 (10.3.0.40) port 10256 (#0)
* allocate connect buffer!
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to hostname:port
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
> CONNECT hostname:port HTTP/1.1
> Host: hostname:port
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.0 502 Bad Gateway
< Server: Zscaler/5.6
< Content-Type: text/html
< Connection: close
<
* Received HTTP code 502 from proxy after CONNECT
* CONNECT phase completed!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 502 from proxy after CONNECT
```

As the output states at the top, `curl` is automatically implementing the `HTTP_PROXY` variable I have in my environment variables, which is needed for other Python tasks. In order to avoid this, I can pass `--noproxy "*"` to `curl` and the request no longer tries to run through the proxy.

I'd like to try to get the equivalent working with Python's `request` module. I know that `requests` will automatically read from the environment variables as well, so I tried to bypass that specifying `proxies=None` in the code:

```
response = requests.get('https://hostname:port/some/api/endpoint', proxies=None, auth=(USER, PASS))
```

But I still get the 502 Bad Gateway. In looking at some questions on SO, it looks as if you can specify the `NO_PROXY` environment variable and provide URLs that should not use the proxy. I tried populating that variable with `https://hostname`, `https://hostname:port`, `https://hostname/*`, `https://hostname:port/*`, and `hostname`. None of which seemed to work. (Are those even the right formats?)

How do I get `requests` to use the equivalent of curl's `--noproxy`?

Comment: You should probably use `proxies={'http': None, 'https': None}`, `proxies=None` it's exactly like omitting it. The `NO_PROXY` should be a *domain*, so `hostname` should be the correct value.

Comment: You are today's hero of the internet. Please submit that as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `proxies` to `None` is like omitting it. You want to specify that the http and https proxies are `None` by passing the value:

```
proxies={'http': None, 'https': None}
```

to the `requests.get` function.

Regarding `NO_PROXY` (or `no_proxy`), its value is a *domain name*, so you shouldn't add `http://` or `https://` in front of its value, just use the domain name `hostname` in your case.